# Forcing reference type

Tags: c++

We have the following common pitfall with our codebase.

```cpp
class FrameworkApplication : public QApplication
{
protected:
    FrameworkApplication(int& argc, char** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv) {}
}
```

This is an abstract class. Each module that fits within the framework must have its own application class that derives from this base class.

It is *imperative* that any class that derives from it *must* pass `argc` as an int reference.

```cpp
class MyApplication : public FrameworkApplication
{
public:
    // wrong! argc is not a reference type
    MyApplication(int argc, char** argv) : FrameworkApplication(argc, argv) {}
}
```

The above mistake is easily made, but it leads to a subtle bug further down the line. One that even the experienced members sometimes fall into and then scratch their head trying to remember the root cause.

And it is very easy to make the above mistake. The compiler does not flag errors or even a warning.

Is there a trick/idiom that we can apply here that forces a compiler error or warning?

**Edit**

I obviously have tried overloading the ctor of base class `FrameworkApplication`...

```cpp
class FrameworkApplication : public QApplication
{
protected:
    explicit FrameworkApplication(int& argc, char** argv);

private:
    explicit FrameworkApplication(int argc, char** argv);
}
```

But that is considered ambiguous and causes a compiler error on the ctor of class `FrameworkApplication`.

Comment: how about passing a (smart) pointer?

Comment: The code is perfectly legal syntax the way it is shown, there is nothing for the compiler to warn on. It just doesn’t exhibit the semantics you want.  Can you change `argc` to a pointer instead? Otherwise, have a look at `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: Unfortunately, Qt's `QApplication` class kind of forces us to use a reference type. I purposefully left the `Qt` tag off this post, because it is not strictly a Qt problem.

Comment: why does it have to be a reference? Is this only to satisfy signature of the `FrameworkAppl` constructor and you merely want to avoid a dangling reference? Or does the caller really depend on `argc` being modified by those classes?

Comment: I am asking because if it is the first you could write a wrapper that stores a copy of `argc` and pass a reference to that copy to the `FramekAppl` constructor

Comment: Why not adding a pure virtual factory method whose parameters would be `int& argc, char** argv`. You would have to ensure (coding rule) that developpers do not create a public constructor for the inherited class though.

Comment: Exactly **where** are you trying to "force a reference type"? `FrameworkApplication` doesn't know about `MyApplication`

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem. There's no reason for `argc` to be a reference. The real requirement is that `argc` is an `lvalue` which remains valid for the lifetime of the `QApplication`.

The almost-solution is to make `argc` a *member* of `FrameworkApplication`. This doesn't work, though, because `FrameworkApplication::argc` will be initialized after the `QApplication` sub-object.

However, the application object is a special case, and so are command lines. There's exactly one per running instance of your program, so you can safely make `FrameworkApplication::argc` a `static` member. This fixes the lifetime.

You'll want to pass `(FrameworkApplication::argc=argc)` as the first argument to `QApplication`. This makes sure `FrameworkApplication::argc` is initialized before `QApplication` uses it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to improve your class design, if this problem keeps happening over and over - even for seniors devs who know what is required - then the design is at flaw.

Since an lvalue `T` will generally convert to a `T&` without any compilation diagnostics, you cannot get the required effect with just an `int&` as any lvalue will satisfy that. What you can do instead is use a type which models the behavior you are looking for.

`std::reference_wrapper<int>` can easily fulfill that purpose. Otherwise, you can roll your own wrapper along similar lines.

P.S.: An even better option would be to avoid the reference entirely and go with a pointer. That has the added advantage of being explicit, which your current design lacks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason we have a reference type is because of [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) which forces this constructor signature.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't you be able to do `public: FrameworkApplication(int* argc, char** argv) : QtApplication(*argc, argv) { }` with a pointer parameter? P.S.: I am not an expert on Qt, so likely missing something there.

Comment: You would now have to assert the pointer in a call to the base class. Nasty.

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways. You need to provide proper lifetime guarantees for your application to work without hitting UB, while also avoiding language supported conversions. Like the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64390156/59081), do the effective compromise and make it static.